# undirected graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, path-finding

How can I find all way to go end in undirected graph ?

```
Graph :

    Node : S, Y, F, T                visualization :    S ----- Y ---- T
    Edge : S --- Y                                       \     /
           Y --- F                                        \   /
           S --- F                                         \ /
           Y --- T                                          F


Assume that

       Start   S 
       Finish  F

       after run   go 

       result will be :

              S F
              S Y F
```

I do not want visit one node more than once. If I visit, this problem become one of NP problems.

EDIT:

input can be any form

```
example:

       edge (S,Y).     OR          edge (Y,S).
       edge (Y,F).                 edge (F,Y).
       edge (S,F).                 edge (F,S).
       edge (Y,T).                 edge (T,Y).
```

BUT OUTPUT MUST BE SAME

Comment: What do you mean by "If I visit, this problem become one of NP problems"?

Comment: ex  S Y T Y S ... S Y T ... WHEN will it terminate ? Maybe never

Comment: What does that have to do with NP?

Comment: Added some more descriptive tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a trace of the visited nodes and exclude those when adding the possible destinations in the next step.

I changed a few edges and added one, to make sure it also works when edges are listed in the 'wrong' order for going from S to F.

```
edge('S','Y').    visualization:    S -- Y -- T
edge('F','Y').                     / \  /
edge('S','F').                    /   \/
edge('Y','T').                   A --- F
edge('A','S').
edge('F','A').
```

In prolog this should roughly look like this:

```
pathBetween(A,A,_):- !, fail.
pathBetween(S,F,Visited) :- (edge(S,F) ; edge(F,S)),
    append(Visited,[S,F],L),
    write(L).
pathBetween(S,F,Visited) :-
    (   edge(S,A) ; edge(A,S)  ),
    not(member(A,Visited)),
    pathBetween(A,F,[S|Visited]).
```

You can use `;` to manually find all the solutions, or [findall](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node96.html).

```
?- findall(Visited, pathBetween('S', 'F', []), _).
[S,F][S,Y,F][S,A,F]
true.
```

Comment: There's no need for BFS. DFS with a closed set suffices.

Comment: @larsmann: Absolutely true, I think I implicitly assumed that the OP would like to find the shortest path first.

Comment: Well, the OP wants to find all paths, so doing a backtracking DFS followed by a sort on length might be a better idea. BFS, esp. when using ordinary lists for queues, is incredibly memory-intensive for larger graphs.

Comment: @larsmans: And DFS might take longer than needed if there are many long paths not  leading to the goal. But either way, the code I posted wasn't actually  BFS in the first place so I'll just remove the reference. The BFS/DFS is slightly off topic anyway. But well spotted, thanks.

Comment: then How can you extract member out of the solution list in order to get expected result, which I defined at question ? Anyway, Thanks for answer

Comment: @user1428237: If you use the `printlists` predicate from [here](http://objectmix.com/prolog/781169-print-list-rows-without-%5B.html#post2816205) on `Solutions`, you should get exactly that.

Comment: @Junuxx: (I hope you're not getting tired of me yet) BFS, when asked for *all* solutions, will also try all the dead ends in the graph.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, but only after having found all the good paths. You could terminate it at some point. In the worst case, DFS hasn't found a single answer by the time BFS has found them all. But it really depends on the graph. It doesn't tire me at all, but I do think we should stop polluting the question ;)

Comment: @gcc (who has since removed his comment): You were right that this only works for directed graphs, I'll change my answer in a moment!

Comment: Fixed, don't know why gcc removed his comment though, it was a good observation.